# Retrieve Multiple Child branches Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ok so I have made a CardView hold one database item(in this case a football player) and adapted it in a RecyclerView. 
My Firebase Database looks like this:

```
Players:
    |---Goalkeepers:
           |--GoalkeeperName
                     |--(And some other data fields)
    |---Defenders:
    |---Midfielders:
    |---Attackers
```

My database reference looks like this:

```
playersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Players").child("Goalkeepers");
```

If I leave the reference as ("Players"), it will give me 4 empty fields representing the Goalkeeper, Defenders, Midfielders and Attackers branch.
How do I display all data from all Position branches such as Goalkeeper, Defenders, Midfielders and Attackers?

Also is there any way of displaying all the players in an organised way with headings in my layout so it looks like this?

```
Goalkeepers(heading)
Goalkeeper1
Goalkeeper2
Defenders (heading)
Defender1
Defender2
```

This is the code from the actual app:

```
public class PlayerList extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mPlayerList;
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference playersRef = rootRef.child("Players");





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_squad_list);
    //playersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Players").child("Goalkeepers");
    playersRef.keepSynced(true);

    //new code
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String typeOfPlayer = ds.getKey();
                Log.d("TAG", typeOfPlayer);

                for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.child(typeOfPlayer).getChildren()) {
                    String player = dSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d("TAG", "    " + player);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    playersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);




    mPlayerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycle_view);
    mPlayerList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mPlayerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Player, PlayerViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Player, PlayerViewHolder>(Player.class, R.layout.player_row, PlayerViewHolder.class, playersRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PlayerViewHolder viewHolder, Player model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setPlayerName(model.getPlayerName());
            viewHolder.setPlayerSurname(model.getPlayerSurname());
            viewHolder.setPlayerPosition(model.getPlayerPosition());

        }
    };


    mPlayerList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}


public static class PlayerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    public PlayerViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setPlayerName (String playerName){
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewName.setText(playerName);
    }
    public void setPlayerSurname (String playerSurname){
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSurname);
        textViewName.setText(playerSurname);
    }
    public void setPlayerPosition (String playerPosition){
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPosition);
        textViewName.setText(playerPosition);
    }
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display those players accordingly to the following database structure:

```
Goalkeepers
    Goalkeeper1
    Goalkeeper2
Defenders
    Defender1
    Defender2
```

Please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference playersRef = rootRef.child("Players");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String typeOfPlayer = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", typeOfPlayer);

            DatabaseReference playerRef = playersRef.child(typeOfPlayer);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String player = dSnapshot.getKey();
                        Log.d("TAG", "    " + player);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            playerRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
playersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

**Edit:**

According to your edited post, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference playersRef = rootRef.child("Players");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String typeOfPlayer = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", typeOfPlayer);

            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.child(typeOfPlayer).getChildren()) {
                String player = dSnapshot.getKey();
                Log.d("TAG", "    " + player);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
playersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Your result must be:

```
Attackers
Defenders
Goalkeepers
    Goalkeeper1
Midfielders
```

Comment: Okay so I have the 2 new database references at the top of my PlayerList class, and deleted my reference. Everything else in the onCreate method and I changed the database reference parameter in the adapter. Instead of playersDatabase I have playersRef. Did I implemented it correctly? If so I only get 4 empty list items which represent the players child branches such as Goalkeeper, Midfielder, Defenders and Attackers. I'm not actually getting the Childs of those branches. My database has 2 main branches "Players" and "Users" and "Players" branch splits into multiple children(position). Thanks

Comment: You should get the exact result I showed at the beginning of my answer. Can you please add a screenshot of your database to see it more clearly?

Comment: Please edit your post with the exact output that you get.

Comment: Not what is displayed on your device, what is printed out in the logcat. With other words what does this line of code return: `Log.d("TAG", "    " + player);`

Comment: Apologies I'm pretty new to Android Studio Development and wasn't really sure what the logcat does but looking at the results it seems like it sees the entries exactly how I want to but below it says no setter/field for the child branches such as Goalkeeper and so on. Do I need to  declare variables and get setters for such? Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that it printed out what I said. The `no setter/field` is basically another problem. This is caused most likely by the incorrect naming of your fields or because you are using incorrect setter and getters or if don't have them at all. So in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question that includes all the necessary details, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: You have been great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ..

```
    private void readData(){
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    rootRef.child("Players").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String typeOfPlayer = ds.getKey();
                Log.d("TAG", typeOfPlayer);

                for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.child(typeOfPlayer).getChildren()) {
                    String player = dSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d("TAG", "    " + player);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

and i hope add internet permission into manifest file..
more information refer this link
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-realtime-database-crud/

Comment: Still doesn't work. Internet permission is in the manifest file. I will have a look at the link. Thanks